# pg(postgresql) is not working in node js using pg library

Tags: node.js, postgresql, electron, node-modules

I am using 'pg' library to connect postgres db with node js inside electron app. This is my code and snapshot of output. I am not getting any response. Please help me. Thanks!

Here is the code :

```
const postgres = require('pg');

const connectionString = 'postgres://localhost:5432/postgres';
var connectionData = {
    connectionString: connectionString
}
const client = new postgres.Client(connectionData);
client.user = 'postgres';
client.password = 'root';
client.connect();

const q = `SELECT * FROM public.text`;
client.query(q, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    for (let row of res.rows) {
        console.log(row);
    }
    client.end();
});
```

This is snapshot :

[snapshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmGBf.jpg)

I have verified with database, there is one record in table.

Comment: Read https://node-postgres.com/features/connecting and choose how you will connect. You seem to mixup connection methods.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Anastazy. But I hadn't mixup methods. It is all there if you will see index.js of this pg library.

Answer (score 2):

I have solve this issue with just updating version of pg.
This is fixed in pg@8.0.6. If you face same issue then try pg version >=8.0.3.

Please feel free to share anything about this if you have other options. Thanks for your support. :)

Comment: Can you link the commit/pull request/bug report about the issue, please?